# Handling spot termination of task nodes in AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

For my Project, we want to create an EMR cluster with ON-DEMAND master, core nodes and spot task nodes. As our entire data is in S3, we want to limit core nodes to 1 and use task nodes only for processing.

As task nodes are spot, I am blocked on how to handle spot-terminations. Whenever spot instances get shut down, I want to create on-demand task nodes in place of them.

What is the best way to identify that task nodes are getting terminated? through describeCluster API call? or through spot termination notice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest Spot Termination Notice is best option. The reclamation process with the addition of a two-minute warning, formally known as a Spot Instance Termination Notice. Your application can use this time to save its state, upload final log files, or remove itself from an Elastic Load Balancer. This change allow more types of applications to benefit from the scale and low price of Spot Instances.

This blog is really a good read for you.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-instance-termination-notices/